# Group Policy and ADMX files

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy

I am trying to create group policies on our domain controller (Windows 2012 Server) to test how our WSUS updates are handled.

Here are the options I want to see: [image: from google]

Here are the options I actually see: [image: my options]

Specifically you can see: I am missing options like "Specify deadline before auto-restart for update installation" and a bunch of others.

From what I read on Google I need to install ADMX files to update my Administrative Templates within the Group Policy Editor. I have installed these (3 of them in fact) and still don't see any of these extra options.

**After you install these ADMX updates do you need to do anything to get them working? 
Anyone know how I get the full range of GP options?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the files from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Group Policy\Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (1709)\PolicyDefinitions
```

To:

```
C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions
```

You may need to change the owner and permissions of the target folder to provide access.  Probably a good idea to make a backup of the target folder before copying the files.

Comment: Is this answer still correct?   From what I've been reading (do NOT assume I am correct) - you copy them to the central SYSVOL store now - and copying them to C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions was the old way ..  Here's where I got my info from:  
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/10/20/step-by-step-managing-windows-10-with-administrative-templates/ ... which was from 2015 .. but this one is less than a month ago: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3087759/how-to-create-and-manage-the-central-store-for-group-policy-administra

Comment: @DHW: Yes, If they are using the central store, that would be the destination folder. The default is to use the local folder.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I had someone demystify it for me yesterday.  To share what was said: The only purpose of templates is to inform the group policy editor so it can display things correctly and create the proper policy files... so if its in C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions - it can do it from that machine .. if its in the central repository - it can do it from any machine.   Once the policy files are created - the templates have nothing to do with the process